# Hiding column when all column cells value is zero

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I want to hide in my report the columns that have all the cells value `0`. Is this possible?

I also generate global footer variables for each column.

Maybe I can access the global footer variable and check if it's `0` then hide the column?

edit1 : I'm using just dynamic jasper.

Comment: `Is this possible?` - Yes, it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Table and in column properties set Column Print When:$F{field_1}!=0
(JR version must be >= 4.00) 
Global variable is not need in this case

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I'm using just dynamic jasper.